# TCP data before session closing

Tags: cocoa, networking, tcp, cocoaasyncsocket

Is there anyway that will allow to get all data sent via tcp before the session gets closed?
What I am getting is I have to close the session from server only after that data is received, and moreover I have to manually pass EOL or carriage-return or "\n" or  "\r".

Any help and suggestions is appreciated.

Comment: TCP always delivers all the sent data before you read EOS. What is your question exactly?

Comment: But in my case it waits for session closing and then only all data is sent. I tried to extract one character at a time and also all full data but in both the situation i have to loop through with "\r" at the end to read next data.

Comment: Then clearly you aren't flushing the output at the appopriate points.

Comment: Please let me know how can i flush the output before retrieving all the data, as I have to encrypt, deserialize and then render it into my  tableviews based on some keys.

Comment: I'm unclear from the question which side is _not_ receiving the data and which side is closing the connection.  Do you mean that you don't receive all data from the server until the server closes the connection?

Comment: @Brian : I have a client on my system and apache running on other, database is on third system. I make a request of session from client, the server sends the data from db, but...only after the session gets closed. I dont want the session to be closed now, because once I get the data, I have to perform some related task. I hope now I am able to give you a clear idea of problem.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya, almost...  By "after the session gets closed" do you mean the client closing the session or the server closing the session?  Note that an HTTP server is free to close the session if it wishes after transmitting all data whether the client wishes the connection to remain open or not.  Also note that the server will not start its response until it sees a blank line after the request, though shutting down client->server side of the link typically has the same result.

Comment: @Brian : By "after the session gets closed" I mean client closes the session by "\n" or "\r". Only after this the data is seen. I did not want to close the session right at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try setting the `SO_LINGER` socket option:

```
GCDAsyncSocket asyncSocket = ...;
struct linger linger;
linger.l_onoff = 1;
linger.l_linger = 30;
int rv = setsockopt([asyncSocket socketFD], SOL_SOCKET, SO_LINGER, &linger, sizeof(linger));
if (rv < 0)
{
    // handle error
}
```

Comment: That wouldn't make any difference to the receiver. All it does is delay the sender for up to 30s in close() while pending data is being sent.

Comment: @EJP What's happened to all the comments on this answer?

Comment: @Anoop-Vaidya This actually solved the issue then?  If so, would you are to explain and perhaps get EJP involved too.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there anyway that will allow to get all data sent via tcp before the session gets closed?

You keep reading data from the socket till `EOF` is received.

> What I am getting is I have to close the session from server only after that data is received

Technically, one can close your write side of the TCP connection, using `shutdown(socket, SHUT_WR)` indicating that this peer is not going to send any more data. But it will still need to read all the data till `EOF` is seen and then `close(socket)`.

> and moreover I have to manually pass EOL or carriage-return or "\n" or "\r"

This has little to do with sockets or TCP, rather with a higher application protocol, such as HTTP. There are libraries available for this popular protocol that simplify this task.